# Matlab Parallel toolbox: Error with parfor

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code as following

```
....
index = 1;
parfor mi=initmu:maxmu
    for la1i=initla+1:(maxla-initla)/stepla+1
        ImageD=uint8(GaussPoisonDenoise(Image, mu(mi), la1(la1i), la2(la1i)));
        p = psnr(ImageD, Image0);
        index=index+1;
    end
end
....
```

But Matlab tells me that "parfor loop cannot run due the way variable index is used". What does that mean? What need I do?

Answer (score 0):

The parfor loop separates the loop to run different loop-iteration at the same time in arbitrary order.

The problem is that the variable "index" increase at the same time in different iteration and by different values.

For example while one matlab-worker is computing the iteration mu=2 and is increasing index by 3, another is computing the iteration mu=10 and increasing index by one.
In this case what is the effective value of index? (index+3 or index+1?)

You cannot use parfor when an iteration in your loop depends on the result of other iteration.

If you need "index" only to count the number of iteration, I think you can calculate it  operating on intmu, maxmu, intla, maxla, stepla. (But certainly you have another pourpose!)

Answer (score 0):

Parfor must only be used when there's no dependency between the several iterations that are to be run. In this case, there is dependency between the two iterations and hence parfor won't work.